How can I instruct clang tidy to not check the readability-identifier-naming for static functions?
I'm running this command to de-camel exported 'c' functions and add a prefix to their name:
clang-tidy -checks='-*, readability-identifier-naming' -config="{CheckOptions: [ {key: readability-identifier-naming.FunctionCase, value: snake_case}, {key: readability-identifier-naming.FunctionPrefix, value: 'spi_'} ] } " --fix-errors *.[ch]

I don't want to add the prefix to static functions, and preferably, not change the name of static functions.
Is there way to do with that with clang-tidy-17?
